# Error when picking random array element in Javascript: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror, splice

I want to pick a random element from an array without repeating, but an error occurred: *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sound')*.

Here's my code:

```
var words = [
  { word: 'major', sound: 'major.mp3'},
  { word: 'apply', sound: 'apply.mp3'},
  { word: 'blue',  sound: 'blue.mp3' },
  { word: 'cat',   sound: 'cat.mp3'  },
  { word: 'class', sound: 'class.mp3'},
  { word: 'code',  sound: 'code.mp3' },
  { word: 'cook',  sound: 'cook.mp3' },
  { word: 'daisy', sound: 'daisy.mp3'},
  { word: 'ease',  sound: 'ease.mp3' },
  { word: 'idea',  sound: 'idea.mp3' }
];

var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length - 5)]; // just added - 5 here
var audio = new Audio();
var playBtn = document.getElementById("play-button");
var guessBtn = document.getElementById("guess-button");
var nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-button");
var correct = document.getElementById("correct");
var incorrect = document.getElementById("incorrect");

playBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  audio.src = randomWord.sound;
  audio.play();
  var name = words.splice(randomWord,1); // just added
  words.push(name); // just added
  })

guessBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box").value;

  if (inputBox == randomWord.word) {
    correct.innerHTML = "Correct!"
  }
  else {
    incorrect.innerHTML = "Incorrect"
  }
})

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  location.reload();
})
```

The audio played smoothly until I attempted to make it not repeat. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Assuming you're trying to get a random number between 0 and the last index of `words`, you're not doing it correctly. Check out this section of the [relevant docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_number_between_two_values).

Comment: You are returning a random number and then subtracting 5 from it (which could be a negative result). This is due to operator precedence. Put parentheses around `words.length -5`, of course you do realize this will only randomize up to 5.

Answer (score 1):

words[Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length - 1))];

I think you need to use like this.

because Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length - 5) can be less than 0

Comment: thanks for the help, but it didn't quite work, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider : 1) building an array of indexes from 0 to words.length, 2) picking a random index 3) getting a word using the random index (the word will be random) 4) deleting the random index  to avoid repetitions. This way, you no dot not need to delete your words and your random index will always be valid.

```
//----------New code-----------------
var indexes = []
for (let i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    indexes.push(i)
}
//-----------------------------------




 playBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      //get a random index value
      let randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random()*words.length))
       //Get your randomword here, using the random index
       var randomWord = words[randomIndex]; 
       //Delete the index so it will not repeat
       indexes.splice(randomIndex,1)
       //This is your code below
       audio.src = randomWord.sound;
       audio.play();
      //var name = words.splice(randomWord,1); // delete this!
      words.push(name); // just added >> is this required?
  })
```

Comment: My audio played with this but still repeats.

Comment: Your code does not seem to update the random word. I edited my answer and moved the added code into the playBtn eventListener function. This way, when a user clicks the play button, a new random index and word will be chosen and played. The random index will be removed from the indexes array, to avoid repetition. Your code was not runnable locally, so I had to guess on the solution.